# Codeigniter class cron doesn't work

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, cron

I have a site developed in codeigniter where I want to use a cron controller.
I have write this controller:

```
class Cron extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // this controller can only be called from the command line
        if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) show_error('Direct access is not allowed');
    }

    function importMeteo()
    {
        $this->load->model('Meteo_model');
        $this->Meteo_model->importFromXml();
    }
}
```

The function importFromXml works fine because if I call it from other controller no problems.

Into my linux server in /etc/crontab I have added this line to call this functuon every 10 minutes:

```
*/10 * * *      root    php /var/www/public/my_site.com/index.php cron/importMeteo
```

But I don't see any change like the function isn't called.

I'm wrong something?

Comment: did you autoloaded the session library ?

Comment: the session library is loaded @DBK

Comment: maybe that's d problem, remove it from autoload. nd try again.

Comment: But I need session library into my site @DBK

Comment: okk wait, before that, does the cron worked ?

Comment: I can't disabled session because we are working on this site sorry @DBK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron entry should be like this

```
*/10 * * * * php /var/www/public/my_site.com/index.php cron importMeteo
```